# Result from NDSolve will not plot

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

[image]

```
Greg1[tmax_, k_, R_, J_, m_, θ0_, ω0_] :=
  NDSolveValue[
    {\!\(TraditionalForm\`\) (J + m*R)*θ''[t] == -(1/4)*k*R*θ[t],
     θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == ω0},
    θ, {t, 0, tmax}]
sol1 = Greg1[10, 800, 0.5, 20, 100, π/16, 0];
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "θ(t)"},
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

I tried to plot `NDSolveValue`, but it said there is no numerical value at `t == 0`. How can I fix it?

Comment: welcome. Please post code in copyable form so folks can run it to see whats going on.

Comment: How can I post in copyable form?

Comment: just copy paste from mathematica to the browser.

Comment: Do ``Clear["Global`*"]`` and try again. You have lingering definitions.

Comment: Where do I have to clear?

Comment: After I put clear, the when t==0 this is solved, but I still cannot plot the graph.

Comment: It only shows the axis like picture above.

Answer (score 1):

You have the bad formatting wrapper `TradionalForm` in your definition of `Greg1`. Get rid of it by converting the cell to Raw Input Form and deleting the `Null` you see there. Then it will work.

```
Greg1[tmax_, k_, R_, J_, m_, θ0_, ω0_] := 
  NDSolveValue[
   {(J + m R) (θ^′′)[t] == -(1/4)k R θ[t], θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == ω0}, 
   θ, {t, 0, tmax}]
sol1 = Greg1[10, 800, 0.5, 20, 100, \[Pi]/16, 0];
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "θ(t)"},
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]